# set default selected for select component in javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok, so from what I found googling around, I can do something like (please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
component.options[component.selectedIndex].defaultSelected = true;
```

But what if I want to change it afterwards? I mean if I do the same action on a different option, will both have `defaultSelected` to true? Do I need to first go trough all the options and set `defaultSelected = false` and only after do a re-assigning?

Also is there a easy way to get the defaultSelected option rather than go trough all the options in a loop and return when defaultSelected = true is reached?

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than one option can have its [deftaultSelected](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-37770574) property set to true. If you don't know which ones have the *defaultSelected* property set and you wish to change it, you must iterate over all of them and set the the one you want to be the default to true and the others to false.

However, there is rarely a need to do so. The *defaultSelected* property is only used when a form is reset to determine which option will be selected by default. If some other option is selected, it will become the selected option and the default selected option is no longer of interest.

Setting the default option after the document has loaded does not, of itself, change the option that is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is what I was looking for. As I said above I want to use the property as somewhat of a hack to keep both the currently selected item and the previously selected one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById('MyDropDown').selectedIndex = i;
```

Where i is the index of the desired option to set as the selected option.

Or are you just wanting to find out what is currently selected?

Comment: This would set option i as the selected value wouldn't it? I need to set i as the default value. This is supposed to be used as a "hack" because on a "onchange" event I need both the selected option and the option that was selected before the event.

Comment: The defaultSelected property has nothing to do with the currently selected option. It may not be set on any option, whether the option is selected or not. If you want to track the selected option, you can use the select's change event and store the last two selected.